# Menu to switch between specific files in illustrator cc (OSX), akin to the "window menu" in a browser or MS office

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, cc-2015

I often have many (many) files open at once to compose infographics from multiple source materials. I know how to toggle using cmd+~, but want a menu of the open files to avoid toggling through so many. I know better than to expect convenience in illustrator (sigh), but perhaps there's some feature I am overlooking?

For clarity, screenshot of the desired illustrator feature (as done in a browser) is in the bottom right of the image below but similar feature is in MS office, others in the "window" menu. The window menu in illustrator offers no such functionality.

[image: Window menu on a browser offers a list of open files]

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator lists open documents at the **bottom of the `Windows` Menu**

`Window > (Document Name)` all the way at the bottom....

[image]